# jQuery dialog button confirm before opening URL

Tags: jquery, function, button, dialog, popup

I am having difficulty creating a button that will pop up a dialog box to 'confirm' if I want to continue to open the URL link or not. However, when I click on the button "google', it automatically directs me to the google website before I even clicked "ok" to view. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

You can view jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uRGJD/76/

HTML:

```
<button class="open" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')">Google</button>

<div class="unique">Are you sure you want to continue?</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.open').on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.unique').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    window.location = link.href;
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.unique {display: none;}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

`<button class="open">Google</button>`

Remove the onclick event from your `<button>`.

Also, you are just creating the jQueryUI dialog. You need to actually need to open it. I suggest looking at the jQueryUI documentation for this widget.

Comment: Thanks. I removed onClick and changed window.location = link.href; to window.open("http://www.google.com"); and it works fine; however, by specifying 'google.com' I wont be able to create buttons to new URLs. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the window.open function inline.

Take it out a put it in a function called doGoogle or something. Then put the doGoogle function in the ok function call.

.dialog will inialize the opening of the dialog as long as the div exists like you have

Judson

Comment: Thanks. I removed onClick and changed window.location = link.href; to window.open("http://www.google.com"); and it works fine; however, by specifying 'google.com' I wont be able to create buttons to new URLs. Any way around this?

Comment: Yes you need to pass variables to window.open so when you call your dialog function set a variable like URL="google.com" then in the button reference it as window.open(URL)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I use is to wrap my .dialog in a function like showDialog(URL)

This way you can pass the URL to the buttons

So you would call it like: onclick="showDialog("google.com")

Then your button would have

window.location.href=URL

Hope this helps.